# Format a number in C# from left side

Tags: c#, formatting

I want to format my number from the left side.

Suppose I have `00.524`, then it should give me `0.524`.

If I have `10.524`, then it should convert it to `10.524`.

This means if I have `0` at the start, I should remove the zero.
Is there any string format like `0:n2` for this?

Comment: `00.524` is not any known number. Where do you see this? Is it in a string perhaps?

Comment: in my application m getting a datatable with this records

Comment: Then your 'number' is actually a string representing a number.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll always have a valid double value, you can do that:

```
string.Format("{0:n2}", double.Parse(stringWithNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

String.Format("{0:0.000}", 00.524);

More on this [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a custom format specifier like:

```
myDouble.ToString("#0.###")
```

Make sure to use a `#` where you want a number to appear only if it is valid and a 0 to appear anywhere you want a zero to appear otherwise.